# Andengine onAreaTouched Rectangle - Android

Tags: android, andengine, sprite, onclicklistener

I am developing a game to Android devices, using Andengine.

I would like to know if there is a simpler way to set the onAreaTouched of an object than doing the following:

```
Sprite mySprite = new Sprite(X, Y, mySpriteTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        //Insert Code Here
        return true;
    }
};
```

I am looking for something like setting up listeners to Buttons in Android

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(...);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then:

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == b.getId())
         doSomething();
}
```

I am looking for it because sometimes I have to set up multiple listeners inside each other, and that makes the code looks funny and complicated.

Comment: see my post for the same functionality as in android:

Answer (score 1):

You are having same type of functionality as in android(If you dont want touch listeners you can use in this way)

```
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.ButtonSprite.OnClickListener;
```

Just implement "OnClickListener" class and perform action on ButtonSprite as follows:

```
ButtonSprite btn = new ButtonSprite(0, 0, mPlayerTiledTextureRegion1, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ButtonSprite arg0, float arg1, float arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Hoping this will helpful